# Is it possible to debug UnhandledExceptionFilters with a debugger?

Tags: c++, windows, exception, uncaughtexceptionhandler

In the Microsoft Windows API, you can use [SetUnhandledExceptionFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680634%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), to set a handler for unhandled exceptions.  The big catch, mentioned on that page, is:

> If an exception occurs ***in a process that is not being debugged***, and
>   the exception makes it to the unhandled exception filter, that filter
>   will call the exception filter function specified by the
>   lpTopLevelExceptionFilter parameter.

(*emphasis added*)

Which basically means, if the process is getting debugged, the debugger gets the exception, and my filter is skipped!

I can test & debug my ExceptionFilter the old-fashioned way, with printfs and trial-n-error.

But am I missing something?  Is there a good way to interactively debug an ExceptionFilter if it is disabled when in a debugger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkout the Resolution section of [KB173652](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/173652) which talks about placing all the code in main/WinMain in a _*try/*_except block like the following.

```
void main (int argc, char **argv)
{
   __try
   {
   // all of code normally inside of main or WinMain here...

   }
   __except (MyUnFilter (GetExceptionInformation()))
   {
      OutputDebugString ("executed filter function\n");
   }
}
```

Another article, [Debugging custom filters for unhandled exceptions](http://www.debuginfo.com/articles/debugfilters.html), describes a couple more techniques in addition to the one above. I personally use the one where you display a message box inside your exception filter and then attach the debugger. I use [IsDebuggerPresent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680345%28VS.85%29.aspx) to determine whether to display the message box or not.

Answer (score 2):

I know this post has been around for a while, but, I just happened upon it searching for something else.  I’m happy to say that what user ‘abelenky’ asks is possible if the filter **exists in a separate dll**.  You can debug an unhandled exception filter using a debugger.  I’ve done it, and, here’s how:

- The exception filter must exist in a separate dll.  You’ll see why later.

You’ll need to add some code to the filter that displays a message box.  I use the following code:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
    AfxMessageBox (_T("At this time, you must attach the debugger to this process in order to debug the filter code."));
#endif
```

The #ifdef is important because you don’t want the code executing in a Release build.  I placed the above code at the very top of my filter.

**To debug the filter**:

1. Build a Release version of your application in Visual Studio
   (instance #1).
2. Build a Debug version of your filter in a second instance of VS (#2).
3. Copy the Debug version of the filter to the Release folder of your
   application.
4. Start your Release application from the Debug menu “without
   debugging”.
5. Cause a crash in your application.
6. When the debug message box (above) appears, change to the second instance (#2) of Visual Studio.
7. In the #2 instance, open the filter project in Debug (if it isn't open) and attach the
   debugger to your Application instance.
8. Set a breakpoint in your filter code after the message box displays.
9. Close the message box and your breakpoint should be hit.
10. Continue to debug your code.